# Why do I keep getting this error: "sh: 1: firefox: not found"?

Tags: python

I don't know why it's not working i mean everything looks good. But when i run it i get this error: "sh: 1: firefox: not found"

```
ID = str("1234")
enter_ID = input("Enter your ID: ")

if enter_ID == ID:
  print("ID is correct please insert your password. ")
  password = str("1234")
  enter_password = input("Enter your password: ")
  if enter_password == password:
    print("Your are now login")
   
    print ("Made by: Aiden") 
    import os
    os.system("firefox") 

  else:
    print("This password is incorrect please try again. ")
else:
  print("ID is not correct please try again ")
```

Comment: maybe firefox not install in same path or it has any restriction

Comment: try `os.system("start firefox")`

Comment: try : `bash $(which firefox)`